# UISegmentedControl selector not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a calls Called Modal that I am running the following code in.

```
    - (void)createAccessoryView
{

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width, 44.0);
    fieldAccessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    fieldAccessoryView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    fieldAccessoryView.tag = 200;

    [fieldAccessoryView setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

    UIBarButtonItem *spaceButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone  target:self action:@selector(done:)];

    UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Previous", @""), NSLocalizedString(@"Next", @""), nil]];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [segmentedControl setMomentary:YES];
    UIBarButtonItem *segmentButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];

    [fieldAccessoryView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:segmentButton, spaceButton, doneButton, nil] animated:NO];

}

-(void)segmentAction:(id)selector
{

}
```

I then create a class that extends Modal and has a few UITextFields. Clicking on a text field brings up the keyboard as expected. Once the keyboard is launched I see the previous / next and done buttons. Clicking done throws and error and doesn't use the segmentAction method as it should. Not really sure why.

here is the stack trace I get after clicking the done button

```
2013-03-13 15:54:33.956 myapp[74194:c07] -[NotesModal done:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80f3fb0
2013-03-13 15:54:33.961 myapp[74194:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NotesModal done:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80f3fb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b54012 0x1470e7e 0x1bdf4bd 0x1b43bbc 0x1b4394e 0x1484705 0x3b82c0 0x5f4a64 0x1484705 0x3b82c0 0x3b8258 0x479021 0x47957f 0x4786e8 0x3e7cef 0x3e7f02 0x3c5d4a 0x3b7698 0x1aafdf9 0x1ad7f3f 0x1ad796f 0x1afa734 0x1af9f44 0x1af9e1b 0x1aae7e3 0x1aae668 0x3b4ffc 0x1786d 0x24b5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: the error that I get is that the selector isn't available

Comment: Can you please post it?

Comment: OK, the problem is in `-[NotesModal done:]`.
do you have any parameter in your `done` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of the error is this:

```
[NotesModal done:]: unrecognized selector
```

Hence, it's crashing because it doesn't recognize the method `done:`.

Make sure that you actually have a `done:` method, such as this:

```
 -(void)done:(id)sender
 {
      // whatever it does here...
 }
```

Note `-(void)done` and `-(void)done:(id)sender` are **not** the same.

Answer (score 1):

this code

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone  
                                                                            target:self 
                                                                            action:@selector(done:)];
```

needs a method

```
-(void)done:(id)selector
{
    //…
}
```

either provide it or change the `UIBarButtonItem` to

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone  
                                                                            target:self 
                                                                            action:@selector(segmentAction:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your `done` method has any parameter.

It needs to be something like:

```
-(void)done:(id)selector
{
    [self dismissModalViewController];
}
```